# Teamproject C# Desktop safe error

Tags: c#, winforms

Me and my friend are working on a teamproject (GIT project). I made the mistake to safe a one part of the project on my desktop (a .cs file). Now the project is messed up because one of the three forms is stored in a different place, "invalid resx file". Is there a way to rollback or fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question really makes no sense. It'll most likely get closed unless you specify what you mean exactly by "everything is messed up" and "safe (save?) a form on my desktop"

Comment: 1. What does teamproject mean, VSTS? Git?.  2. What does messed up mean?  3. Save a form? Do you have code examples?